# jQuery autocomplete: pre-cache query to increase performance?

Tags: mysql, json, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery autocomplete field that looks up city names and corresponding ZIP (US Postal Code) when the user begins typing the city name in the field.

The MySQL database contains about 44,000 rows of US ZIP codes. The query itself runs quickly (0.0002 sec) when selecting all citynames and ZIP codes.

Would there be any benefit to "pre-caching" all of the results (SELECT `place_name`, `postal_code` FROM `postal_codes` WHERE `country_code` = 'US') so that the auto-complete function loads quicker for the user?

EDIT:  The entire JSON list is 600KB and loads in 2-3 seconds in the browser (according to Google Chrome Console)

Current Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('#from_country').change(function(){
  var val = this.value;
  $("#from_zip").autocomplete({
    source: "json-list-live-production.php?country=" + val,
    minLength: 4,
  });
}).change()


$('#del_country').change(function(){
  var val = this.value;
  $("#del_zip").autocomplete({
    source: "json-list-live-production.php?country=" + val,
    minLength: 4,
  });
}).change()


});
</script>

<input type="text" class="input_text" name="from_zip" id="from_zip"  />

<input type="text" name="del_zip" id="del_zip"  />
```

Comment: You could precache it, but then you have to contend with bandwidth. The full list will be quite big. 'precaching' as you call it, only really makes sense if its quicker to transfer the whole list to the client, than it is to just do the lookup on demand. If the user has to wait 10 seconds to download the whole list, that is worse than not having the cache. (ie unless your list is quite small, it probably wont make sense)

Comment: Look at [`jQuery Autocomplete's Remote Caching demo`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using the GeoNames.org webservice + jQuery Autocomplete for looking up ZIP/Postal codes is the fastest method.

```
$( "#from_zip" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 50,
        placename_startsWith: request.term,
        country: "US"
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.postalCodes, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.placeName + (item.adminCode1 ? ", " + item.adminCode1 : "") + " (" + item.postalCode + ")",
            value: item.postalCode
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
    messages: {
        noResults: null,
        results: function() {}
    },

});
```